# PyCharm debug console not working

Tags: pycharm

I can run the debugger and put breakpoints to active the console but it appears as if the console doesn't pick up the code I am entering.

I can just type anything but I don't get any ouput,

```
a=2
print(a)
sfgsmk
..g.bbcvdgdggh
```

Any ideas how I can get the debug console to run the code I am typing and how to get it to show output.

I am using Community Edition 2017.1.4

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue!

Comment: There is a ticket for this here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FPY-24875

Comment: I am also experiencing this in Professional Edition 2017.1.5

Answer (score 27):

Click on the button `Show Python Prompt`.

[image]

In order to have the prompt automatically appear, go to `Preferences`>`Build, Execution, Deployment`>`Console`> check `Always show debug console`

Comment: This is exactly what is broken.

Comment: Isn't there an option to load / show the prompt at break automatically? In another project PyCharm does load it, but I can't find the option...

Comment: Ah thanks, I was looking for exactly this option. Seems it is checked by default now, and I wanted it unchecked. Couldn't find it in the settings myself.

Comment: This does not answer the question!

Comment: this button (and the whole column of buttons above it) don't seem to be available to me. I deleted the `.idea` directory and re-created the pycharm project and seems to work again.

Comment: Add mentioned in another answer: uncheck 'Emulate terminal in output console', then the full sidebar appears.

Answer (score 21):

Adding `-s` to 'Additional Arguments' in the run configuration helped me with the same issue.

Comment: I don't see 'Additional Arguments' in the run configuration on pycharm 21.03. Do you mean Parameters or Interpreter options? @karu

Comment: 'Additional Arguments' is not available for a 'Python Run Configuration' (but it is e.g. for a 'Python pytest Run Configuration')

Answer (score 9):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22505) but the workaround is to add `JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING` into your environment variables (no value needed for this key) of your run/debug configuration. This resolved the issue for me on Pycharm Professional Edition 2017.1.5

Comment: There's a related issue regarding pytest which is still open. This solution seems to work for me as well as the recommended solution of adding `-s` to the arguments.

Comment: No solution seem to work for me with PyCharm 2020 1.2, Windows 10

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with PyCharm 2020.3 (and earlier versions) under Ubuntu 20.04 with MATE. From the answers and comments it seems that there are multiple possible reasons for this behaviour.

In my case, the debugger console responded at some breakpoints (e.g. near the beginning of the program), but not for others.

What fixed the problem for me is enabling the "Gevent compatible" checkbox the File → Settings → Build, Execution and Deployment →  Python Debugger (not "Debugger").

[image: Screenshot of Settings dialog]

[Relevant YouTrack issue (PY-9372)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9372)

Answer (score 4):

I'm on PyCharm 2019.2 and I had to check the `Execution > Run with Python Console` checkbox in the Run/Debug Configurations to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today, and the fix for me was to go into the Run/Debug Configuration and uncheck `Execution->Emulate terminal in output console`.

After unchecking that, I now get
`>>>`
when I hit a breakpoint, and it's responsive. It does precede each line with `Out[1]:`, `Out[2]:`, and I have no idea why, but at least it's working.

Comment: This worked for me, seems like `Run with Python Console` option is incompatible with `Emulate terminal in output console` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was using pyCharm 2018.1.2 for some time. The debugger was working just fine while all of a sudden it stopped working. I am mentioning this to clarify that mine was working at first. Anyway, there wasn't any change to justify this crack down.

To me, the **solution** that worked was the *File->Invalidate caches/Restart...* and then *Invalidate and Restart*.

Edit:

Although the above solution worked for a while it reverted to the buggy state soon after.

The final (until further notice) solution for me was to **remove** the **old PyCharm folder** in my home folder (`/home/xxxx/.PyCharmCE2018.1/` in my case) and start a new project. Basically I removed every cache and configuration the PyCharm has used so a let radical solution might also work, like just removing the cache (`/home/xxxx/.PyCharmCE2018.1/system/caches` in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Do it as @karu mentioned.
In pycharm ce 2020, you can add -s in additional Arguments.

1. From menu, Run -> Edit Configurations
2. Add -s in to single file or template pytest like [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPYba.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using PyCharm 2019.3. What works for me was to go to `Edit Run Configuration` then uncheck everything under `Execution`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and even tried different PyCharm versions without success.

In the end the reason for debugging console not working was that somewhere in the repo `sys.out` and `sys.stderr` were being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Am using PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition). I had the same issue. It worked after I selected these options which clears caches under
File -> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Pythong Debugger
selected these options:

1. Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging
2. Collect run-time types information for code insight --> clears caches
3. Gevent compatible

Apply those changes. It worked for me.
[image: Python Debugger Options]

Comment: I advise against choosing *"Collect run-time types information for code insight"* because strange errors start happening if the cache becomes stale.