# Can I make Python console of PyCharm access debugging context?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I would like to execute arbitrary Python commands in Python console so that they can access current local (and global, any) variables of function during debugging process, like in Matlab debugging.

Is it possible in Python?

**UPDATE**

I don't have button described by @nanotek

[image]

Highlighted button, located in the same place does the opposite thing: it dispays console variables. As you see, console doesn't see `found_features` variable, which is in currently traced program above.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a common feature of the debugger.

While the debugger is running, click on `Console`, and then the button `Show Python Prompt`. You will have access to all the variables available at that state.

[Recently some people were complaining about this not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177482/pycharm-debug-console-not-working/45177589#45177589) If you are having issues, try updating to the latest version. I'm on the latest EAP and did not experience this issue.

[image]

Comment: The prompt can also appear automatically when you hit a break point. Go to `Settings > Build, Execution and Deployment > Console > Always show debug console`. Awesome

Comment: Do you mean that when the button is "clicked" it doesn't display the prompt for you, and when it's "unclicked" it does? I'm using 2017.2.3 and I still see the above behavior, but they might have changed it in a later version, or there could be some quirks depending on what you're debugging. Are you running into any issues?