# PyCharm: Use python console for debugging

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, ipython

I just wanted to know if there is a way in PyCharm to use the debug console as an "all-rounder". I.e. try out commands, create variables and debug Python scripts so that the debug console still remains interactive. Spyder has exactly this feature and I have been looking for this in PyCharm for a long time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm running Python file always opens a new console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831152/pycharm-running-python-file-always-opens-a-new-console)

Comment: This link is very similar to my question but I am still trying to figure out how to debug code with the current python console and have it still interactive. This is not answered in this linked question. I dont want to use the debug console. I want to use the console in which I try all my commands.

Comment: In that case try this one [attaching the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939458)

Comment: I probably looked already through all the hints in stackoverflow. And this one too and it is not what I want. I am wondering how Spyder manages it to have this nice feature and PyCharm doesnt?

Comment: If there was a way to connect the python console to the debug console (expose variables, etc from the debug console to the python console), this would be great.

Comment: @quickbug Agreed! Let's see if a little bounty could do the trick

Comment: @vestland. Sorry I did not see you answered my comment. Should not have delete it. The fact is I found the solution (see my answer) and it was pretty much under my nose, so close I could not see it :-D

Comment: @quickbug No problem! Awesome that you found a solution!

Answer (score 3):

Using PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Community Edition),
When you debug in pycharm, there are two tabs at the bottom left: "debugger" and "console". The "console" tab does exactly what you want [image: Screen shot of the bottom left corner of my screen showing myself messing around with my data]

Answer (score 3):

[From this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177589/3821425)

You might be missing the `Show Python Prompt` button

[image]

In order to have the prompt automatically appear, go to `Preferences`>`Build, Execution, Deployment`>`Console`> check `Always show debug console`